# Unity variable needs to work unfied in the same script on multiple gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script attached to 4 gameobjects which has a trigger and adds score if the collider passes the trigger correctly. It does update the score correctly but updates 4 separate scores ( 4 instances of the **score** variable. I need to update the score unifiedly for all of the 4 gameobjects.

Here is my code

```
bool isDead;
private int score;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    isDead = false;
    score =0;

}


void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other){
    if (other.gameObject.name.ToLower () == this.name) {
        Debug.Log ("you won");
        score = score+1;
        GameObject.Find("ScoreText").GetComponent<Text>().text = score.ToString();
    } 
    else {
        Debug.Log ("you lose");
        isDead = true;
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }
    Destroy (other.gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Make field score static.
- Create new class for managing the score.